# How to subset by date in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I am trying to subset by date and I am able to use some code found here but the new data set contains all of the data in the original data set NOT data with the date of 6/4/18 only.

My data set name is Full and my column heading is Date.

here is the code:

```
Full$date <- as.Date(Full$Date, format= "%m/%d/%Y")
Firstday <- subset(Full, Date = "6/4/18" & date < "6/5/18")
```

Here is the example of the data

```
Date    Weight    Length  Metabolic rate ext.
6/4/18     45        150      8
6/4/18     35        145      9
6/8/18     15        125      10 
6/8/18     16        100      2
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve here.  Consider posting some example data that represents `Full`, and show your expected output.  Explain why you have `Date` and `date` as separate variables, and what the purpose of those two conditions are in `subset()`.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I am very new to working with R and using this language. I do  not have a reason why I have Date and date as separate variables. Here is a example of the data.

Comment: It's best if you edit your post rather than try and include all that in a comment. Also, you can probably narrow down the example data to just the critical fields. Have a look at the guidelines for how to build a [mcve].

Comment: It's two equal signs, `Date == "6/4/18"`.

Comment: To compare dates, you need to have both sides to be dates. Something like: `Firstday <- subset(Full, date == as.Date("2018-6-4"))`. `date <  as.Date("2018-6-5")` is also not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to select only "6/4/18" you could filter it out using:

```
library(dplyr)
Firstday <- Full %>% filter(Date == "6/4/18")
```

Comment: This worked to drop that day but I am hoping to select this particular day.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Well, first you should know what you want to achieve:) By doing Date == "6/4/18" & date < "6/5/18" you tell you want to select "6/4/18" and anything less than  "6/5/18". As you may see, it this case, your date constraints overlaps so it's not what you want. Selecting single date point gives what you want.

Comment: Also how would you select a range of dates?

Comment: Easy. Say you want to select last weeks observations:

Full %>% filter(Date > "13/7/18", Date < "20/7/18") 

or even:

Full %>% filter(between(Date, "13/7/18", "20/7/18"))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176437/discussion-between-jacob-bowman-and-aleksandr-voitov).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a column of class `Date` and want to filter by date, just use that column.

```
Firstday <- subset(Full, date == as.Date("6/5/18", format= "%m/%d/%y")
```

Note, however, that when coercing column `Date` your format seems to be wrong:

- **with two digits years use `%y` not `%Y`**.