# Change sample period in r time series regression

Tags: r, time-series

Apologies, I am sure there is a quick answer, but google can't find it...

How do I change the sample period of a timeseries (GARCH specifically) regression. I have data from April 2019 to April 2020. How do I make it from January 2020 to April 2020?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subset by date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447665/how-to-subset-by-date-in-r)

Comment: Yes, that's the way I have been doing it but was hoping there could be a more direct way, e.g. an option: smpl = (2000/09/01; 2010/01/01)

Comment: You must be sure that your date column is really in a date format firstly. Then you can filter them easily. Look [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420155/subset-rows-according-to-a-range-of-time)  or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285626/selecting-timestamps-within-range-in-r) please.

Answer (score 0):

Found it https://rdrr.io/cran/xts/man/subset.xts.html

It turns out it is quite straightforward.